# Advice: size up one instance or create two small instances

Tags: linux, web-server, load-balancing, linux-networking

Somewhat new to advanced server configs and trying to figure out how to decide if I should split my small instance into two separate small machines (one db and one app server) or one bigger machine. Basically i dont know what metrics I should be looking at to guide my decision.

1. What tools can I use to look at metrics (currently running graphite/collectd/statsd)
2. Which metrics would tell me the solution that will be more efficient?

I am trying to be as specific as possible, sorry if the questipn seems too broad.

EDIT: details about apps

I have 4 django apps running on a small instance. One of them pulls a large number of records from a database based on user input ( up to about 60,000 at most)

This app tends to suck a lot of memory and starts making the machine swap when it is processing all the data for return in the view.

Comment: Must you really return all 60,000 records at once? Optimizing your database queries may get you a lot of benefits.

Comment: I don't see a way I can avoid returning them all at once. Can you give a generic example of what that would look like?

Comment: That's a question you were supposed to answer! Is the user actually receiving all of those records in a single request? This usually is not the case.

Comment: yes they are receiving them in a single request. they are all data points that need to be graphed.

Comment: Caching would be the first thing I would look into, then. At all levels. And maybe whether something like PostGIS or some other specialized tools can help you.

Comment: yeah I am looking into that as well

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at top first. Is your application spending more time waiting for IO or CPU/RAM limited?

Scaling out versus up is a tough question and very application dependant but over all a single box with 2x the resources is more efficient than 2 boxes with 1/2 as much power because in the second case you're paying the OS overhead twice and does not have to deal with ACID stuff (unless you can deal with eventual consistency but still there is the overhead of whatever is syncing your data).

But it depends - more details on the application and what you expect it's bottlenecks are would help.

Comment: thanks for your response. I've added some more details to the post